# Piecewise function created from list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, piecewise

I have a list of values called EDFh3. This contained values which are partitioned by 3 where it is in the format

```
EDFh3 = {{value, lowerbound condition, upperbound condition},{},{},...}
Piecewise[{{#1, #2 <= x < #3}}] & @@@ EDFh3
```

I am trying to create a piecewise function that contains all of the values in EDFh3 into one piecewise function. Instead when I apply it to the Piecewise function I get a list of piecewise functions. Is there any way to combine piecewise function? Alternatively is there a way to edit the code above to produce one piecewise function initially.

Comment: `Piecewise[{#1, #2 <= x < #3} & @@@ EDFh3]` You just need to move your closing `]` (and remove the outer list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Piecewise[{#1, #2 <= x < #3} & @@ # & /@ EDFh3]
```

or

```
Piecewise[{#[[1]], #[[2]] <= x < #[[3]]} & /@ EDFh3]
```